# Why do I get a "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 227: invalid start byte" error

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I was preparing an assignment for my class when I get "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 227: invalid start byte" error even though the text file I am using looks ok.
Here is my code:

```
with open("Oyuncular.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
gs_listesi = []
fb_listesi=[]
bjk_listesi=[]
for i in file:
i = i[:-1]
elemanlar = i.split(",")
if(elemanlar[1]=="BJK"):
bjk_listesi.append(elemanlar[0])
elif(elemanlar[1]=="GS"):
gs_listesi.append(elemanlar[0])
else:
fb_listesi.append(elemanlar[0])
with open("BJK_Oyuncular.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as file2:
for i in bjk_listesi:
file2.write(bjk_listesi[i]+ "\n")
with open("GS_Oyuncular.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as file3:
for i in gs_listesi:
file3.write(gs_listesi[i]+ "\n")
with open("FB_Oyuncuları.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as file4:
for i in fb_listesi:
file3.write(gs_listesi[i]+ "\n")
```

My text file:

```
Fernando Muslera, GS
Victor Ruiz, BJK
Harun Tekin, FB
Okan Kocuk, GS
Loris Karius, BJK
Mauricio Isla, FB
Christian Luyindama, GS
Enzo Roco, BJK
Simon Falette, FB
Jean Michael Sei, GS
Domagoj Vida, BJK
Taylan Antalyalı, GS
Serdar Aziz, FB
Emre Belözoğlu, FB
Mohamed Naser Elsayed Elneny, BJK
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Try deleting this line and see if it works. `Emre Belözoğlu, FB`

Comment: Emre Belözoğlu has Turkish symbols in it yet encoding with utf-8 should overcome that shouldn't it?

Comment: And it does not work

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues `gs_listesi[i]` will throw an error because `i` is of type text. Also you will get the error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` because `file3` when it is referenced in `file4`. I am not able to get the error you posted see the code below.

```
with open("Oyuncular.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    gs_listesi = []
    fb_listesi=[]
    bjk_listesi=[]
    for i in file:
        i = i[:-1]
        elemanlar = i.split(",")
        if(elemanlar[1]=="BJK"):
            bjk_listesi.append(elemanlar[0])
        elif(elemanlar[1]=="GS"):
            gs_listesi.append(elemanlar[0])
        else:
            fb_listesi.append(elemanlar[0])
    print(gs_listesi)
    print(fb_listesi)
    print(bjk_listesi)
    with open("C:\\Py\\Stackoverflow\\BJK_Oyuncular.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as file2:
        for i2 in bjk_listesi:
            file2.write(i2 + "\n")
    with open("C:\\Py\\Stackoverflow\\GS_Oyuncular.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as file3:
        for i3 in gs_listesi:
            file3.write(i3 + "\n")
    with open("C:\\Py\\Stackoverflow\\FB_Oyuncuları.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as file4:
        for i4 in fb_listesi:
            file4.write(i4 + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read your file as if it were encoded in UTF-8, but it appears to be encoded in [Windows-1254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254). You could try saving it in UTF-8 from your text editor or loading it with:

```
open("Oyuncular.txt", "r", encoding="windows-1254")
```

---

Here's how I figured that out. First of all, have a look at the error message.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 227: invalid start byte

This is saying that it found a byte with value 0xFD in the file, which isn't valid as the start byte in a multi-byte character in UTF-8. So it seems the file isn't in UTF-8. I guessed you probably saved this file on a Windows computer that's defaulting to storing text in some 8-bit encoding. Since you have Turkish characters, I searched to find out what is the default Turkish code page in Windows. Sure enough, in Windows-1254, it has `ı` encoded as 0xFD. To double-check, I copied your text, saved it as Windows-1254 with CRLF line endings and tried reading it in Python:

```
$ python3 -c "open('f2.txt','rt',encoding='utf-8').read()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 227: invalid start byte
```

Perfect, the same error message. Now if you consult a [list of Python's standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) you'll find that `windows-1254` is one of them, so you can use that when you're reading in the file.